# Help needed, bevel-modifier: Some edges produce very sharp cornes

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

**The problem: Some edges produce very sharp corners while other are OK**. Please see images.

I cannot get this object right (part of a larger piece) and guess I still do not quite get the modifier.

Seems to me there is all to many parameters (from my humble perspective), to test and find a proper adjustment. Right now I trying to scrub the value bars randomly hoping for a OK result yet with no consistent method.

A question to you Blender-users with hopefully more insights than me:

Is there any settings in the modifier-controls you always choose to get a useful result? [spraycover.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HArDguNxbCPPSUEkucnS3iXqd3JQhnYg/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Pointed cornes appears where protruding element meets cylinder]

Comment: Have you tried playing with the Outer and Inner drop downs in the Miter Type section? Try 'Arc' and see if it helps.

Comment: @John is right, *Miter Outer > Arc* will help a lot. Also, the Bevel Profile is set to 1 which is causing weird shading as well.

Comment: Eureka! 
I'll NEVER had figured out that on my own: Outer == Arch, Segment == 3 and Profile == 0.5. These settings made everything nice and smooth. Thanks both of you!